# How can I prove this property about linearly polarized waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization, plane-wave

So I'm studying electromagnetic waves. The current topic is polarization.
My professor material says in one part that the electric field of a monochromatic linearly polarized wave propagating through the z-axis can be written as:

$$E_x = E_0\cos\varphi\cos(\omega t) $$
$$E_y = E_0\sin\varphi\cos(\omega t) $$

But I can not see why. I even tried to prove this but failed miserably. Could someone give a hint of how could I prove this?

Comment: Try to be more precise about what you are actually trying to prove.

Comment: I was trying to prove why I can write a linearly polarized wave in the way I wrote above.

Comment: So what do you know about linearly polarized waves? What specific things do you need to show in order to prove this? What have you tried?

Comment: After thinking about it I guess that to prove that a linearly polarized wave can be written as it is up there I have to think of a coordinate system rotated by a certain angle where I have a linearly polarized wave parallel to the x axis . Then just write the rotation matrix and describe the wave in any other coordinate system.

Comment: Good approach, try to show your work and where you get stuck when you're done.